# unsupported type for timedelta days component: NoneType

Tags: python, django

I am very new to python/django and I have encoutered the above error. I have read some posts but nothing seems to help. In my app the user gets to chooce a reminder from three choices and if he chooses the third option "Select Days", he types the number of days in th reminderx field. 
So, here is my model:

```
class Event(models.Model):

    # some other fields

    reminder=models.IntegerField('Reminder', default=0, choices=REMINDER_STATUS)
    reminderx = models.IntegerField('Days',blank=True, null=True)
```

and here is my code in my view:

```
    today = date.today()
    a = Event.objects.filter(del_f=0)       
    is_today = []
    is_week=[]
    is_custom =[]

    for i in a:
        print('i:',i)
        reminder = i.reminder

        if reminder == 1 :
            rtoday = i.start_date.date() - timedelta(days=1)
            print('rtoday:',rtoday)
            if rtoday == today:
                is_today.append(i)  
        if reminder == 2 :
            rweek = i.start_date.date() - timedelta(days=7)
            if rweek == today:
                is_week.append(i)            

        if reminder == 3 :
            reminderx = i.reminderx
            rcustom = i.start_date.date() - datetime.timedelta(days= reminderx)
            if rcustom == today:
                is_custom.append(i)

    context['today'] = is_today
    context['week'] = is_week
    context['custom'] = is_custom

    return context
```

thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Which kind of error did you receiced?

Comment: I deleted my answer since it is not answering your question. If you typed the number in a form then you need to process the form here we well.

Comment: First, Thanks for all your help . I am typing in the form. My code above is in my ListView in my def get_context_data. It works fine with my other choices.

Comment: Ok I have realized I'm  looking this all wrong. The problem is not in my def. So sorry for wasting your time!! I'm a total newbie in programming !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly states that the `days` parameter to `timedelta()` is `None` (it expects an `int`). In your code, you only have one line where you are calling `timedelta()` with a variable for `days`:

```
rcustom = i.start_date.date() - datetime.timedelta(days= reminderx)
```

So all that means is that the variable `reminderx` is `None`. And if you look at your model definition, `reminderx` can be null. You either need to make the model not accept nulls or have some default value when using the attribute:

```
reminderx = i.reminderx or 1 # one day if nothing is specified
rcustom = i.start_date.date() - datetime.timedelta(days= reminderx)
```